# Turning a GET variable into a session variable

Tags: php

How do I turn the variable below into a session variable?

```
$url = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// to set it
$_SESSION['url'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['url']);

// to get it
$url = $_SESSION['url'];
```

Answer (score 3):

First, initialize your session, then set the variable.

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['url'] = $_GET['url'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I ditched your `mysql_real_escape_string()`. There is no reason to do that before saving it as a session variable.

Your best bet is to use it where the context requires it, e.g. in a SQL string.

Better still, use bound parameters with PDO.

```
session_start();
$url = $_GET['url'];
$_SESSION['url'] = $url
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to start the session with
    session_start();
first, either, and the same on every page you use the session variable.